# Loop an array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, undefined

I am getting an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')" in this function, which is responsible for fetching replies from a tweet(code is little bit commented so you understand what lines are doing):

```
fetchReplies: async () => {
    // THIS IS RETURNING AN ARRAY OF IDs
    const tweetIds = await SQL('SELECT tweet_id FROM twitter_tweets WHERE twitter_id = 11348282')


    tweetIds.forEach(async (id) => {
        let tweetsResponse = await twitter.get(`tweets?ids=${id.tweet_id}&tweet.fields=conversation_id`)
        
        // THIS IS NUMBER WHICH IS DIFFERENT FOR EVERY TWEET
        let conversation_id = tweetsResponse.data[0].conversation_id

        let tweetReplies = await twitter.get(`tweets/search/recent?query=conversation_id:${conversation_id}&tweet.fields=in_reply_to_user_id,author_id,created_at,conversation_id`, { max_results: 10 })

        tweetReplies.data[0].forEach(reply => {
            console.log(reply.text)
        })
    }
}
```

This way of looping an array works if only one id is returned in "tweetIds", but here i have multiple ids and multiple replies for each id(tweet)

This is data(tweetReplies):

```
{
  data: [
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-21T19:58:07.000Z',
      id: '1528102862743642118',
      author_id: '1510483474096050182',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '11348282',
      conversation_id: '1524795250140762116',
      text: '@NASA @chandraxray Why is it black'
    },
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-19T12:32:51.000Z',
      id: '1527266032250912768',
      author_id: '2352974252',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '2352974252',
      conversation_id: '1524795250140762116',
      text: '@NASA @chandraxray 2/2 time is slowing down. The same goes for other space objects. simply due to gravity, they affect the speed of photons and, accordingly, the speed of information.'
    },
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-19T12:32:13.000Z',
      id: '1527265868928933893',
      author_id: '2352974252',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '11348282',
      conversation_id: '1524795250140762116',
      text: "@NASA @chandraxray 1/2 Hmmm, what I think now is that if a black hole doesn't slow down time, it's only because of the low speed of light. The time is the same, but because the light near the black hole expands more slowly, the information reaches us more slowly and therefore it seems to us that"
    },
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-17T12:33:53.000Z',
      id: '1526541514725150723',
      author_id: '1309693356570628105',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '11348282',
      conversation_id: '1524795250140762116',
      text: '@NASA @chandraxray Fantastic!!!'
    }
  ],
  meta: {
    newest_id: '1528102862743642118',
    oldest_id: '1526541514725150723',
    result_count: 4
  }
}
{
  data: [
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-21T02:15:16.000Z',
      conversation_id: '1524744614623821824',
      id: '1527835385006395392',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '11348282',
      author_id: '1518671966294618112',
      text: '@NASA @hanksportster @ehtelescope @chandraxray You said hole'
    },
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-20T05:41:45.000Z',
      conversation_id: '1524744614623821824',
      id: '1527524963028451328',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '11348282',
      author_id: '1524760776934051840',
      text: '@NASA @ehtelescope @chandraxray Wow, just amazing'
    },
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-18T16:08:17.000Z',
      conversation_id: '1524744614623821824',
      id: '1526957858771935232',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '11348282',
      author_id: '1522886732739457027',
      text: '@NASA @ehtelescope @chandraxray Has long has you dont start calling it Azatoth and you dont send people search flooded city in Pacific abysses'
    },
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-18T12:58:11.000Z',
      conversation_id: '1524744614623821824',
      id: '1526910019429605376',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '11348282',
      author_id: '1420225543476326401',
      text: '@NASA @skorch__ @ehtelescope @chandraxray Sorry to bother.. did you guys of NASA saw the @BabyOKBears around there ? they told me are going the moon..'        
    },
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-17T17:56:39.000Z',
      conversation_id: '1524744614623821824',
      id: '1526622742941868033',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '11348282',
      author_id: '1518643692994633730',
      text: '@NASA @ehtelescope @chandraxray Can it consume us faster  please  im tired'
    }
  ],
  meta: {
    newest_id: '1527835385006395392',
    oldest_id: '1526622742941868033',
    result_count: 5
  }
}
{
  data: [
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-21T02:15:16.000Z',
      conversation_id: '1524744614623821824',
      id: '1527835385006395392',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '11348282',
      author_id: '1518671966294618112',
      text: '@NASA @hanksportster @ehtelescope @chandraxray You said hole'
    },
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-20T05:41:45.000Z',
      conversation_id: '1524744614623821824',
      id: '1527524963028451328',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '11348282',
      author_id: '1524760776934051840',
      text: '@NASA @ehtelescope @chandraxray Wow, just amazing'
    },
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-18T16:08:17.000Z',
      conversation_id: '1524744614623821824',
      id: '1526957858771935232',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '11348282',
      author_id: '1522886732739457027',
      text: '@NASA @ehtelescope @chandraxray Has long has you dont start calling it Azatoth and you dont send people search flooded city in Pacific abysses'
    },
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-18T12:58:11.000Z',
      conversation_id: '1524744614623821824',
      id: '1526910019429605376',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '11348282',
      author_id: '1420225543476326401',
      text: '@NASA @skorch__ @ehtelescope @chandraxray Sorry to bother.. did you guys of NASA saw the @BabyOKBears around there ? they told me are going the moon..'        
    },
    {
      created_at: '2022-05-17T17:56:39.000Z',
      conversation_id: '1524744614623821824',
      id: '1526622742941868033',
      in_reply_to_user_id: '11348282',
      author_id: '1518643692994633730',
      text: '@NASA @ehtelescope @chandraxray Can it consume us faster  please  im tired'
    }
  ],
  meta: {
    newest_id: '1527835385006395392',
    oldest_id: '1526622742941868033',
    result_count: 5
  }
}
```

Comment: Just check `data` is defined and is a non-empty array, then iterate over it?

Comment: if(tweetReplies.data) solved my problem, thank you so much...

Comment: You may also want to use `Array.isArray(tweetReplies.data)`, so that if it's any other data type, you don't get the same error :)